# Create Random sparse signal with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, signals, sparse-matrix

In Matlab I use the following to simply create a random sparse signal.

```
N = 100; % Total length of sparse signal;
n = 20; % number of non-zero elements;
x = zeros(N,1);
r = -5 + (5+5)*rand(n,1); %random signal amplitude between -5 and 5
k = randi([0 100],1,n); % locations of the sparse singal
x(k) = r; % The sparse signal
```

With the above Matlab code, I get my desired sparse signal x of Length 100 with nonzero elements in the locations given by k. Is there a simple way to do this in Python, numpy ? Actually, I am learning Python and trying to convert the above code. Basically, I can convert all of the above which is quite similar in Python but i cannot seem to convert the line

```
x(k) = r; % The sparse signal
```

how do I do this in Python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my own answer for the above. For now, it is sufficient for me to translate the above Matlab snippet as follows:

```
def createSparseSignal(N,n):
    sig = np.zeros(N)
    r = 5*np.random.rand(n,1)
    k = np.random.randint(1,100,n)

    a = 1
    for j in range(n):
        i = a*j + 1
        sig[i*k[j]] = r[j]
        a = j-j

    return sig
```